# How can I hide and show div by clicking a radio button using javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have two divs like

```
<div id="exist">
<p>OK</p>
</div>

<div id="new">
    <p>Not OK</p>
</div>
```

I also have two radio buttons like

```
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="exist_radio" value="existing" checked="">Existing
  </label>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="new_radio" value="new">New
  </label>
```

Now I have to show only one div by clicking a radio button.
How can I do that in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

```
  /* JS */
  window.onload    = (function(){

    var radio1      = document.getElementById('exist_radio');
    var radio2      = document.getElementById('new_radio');
    var div1        = document.getElementById('exist');
    var div2        = document.getElementById('new');

    //....

    var show = function(id)
    {
        id.style.display = 'block';
    }

    var hide = function(id)
    {
        id.style.display = 'none';
    }     

    hide(div1);
    hide(div2);

    radio1.onclick = function()
    {
        hide(div1);
        show(div2);
    }

    radio2.onclick = function()
    {
        hide(div2);
        show(div1);
    }

  });
```

for document.getElementById... you can write a some wrapper of course

**note:** my sample it's only show how to do that with native javascript... for production I recommend to split logic of events, operation, etc. and use Backbone :)

Comment: be careful, this sample it's really simple to show "how to do that.." on native lang. I hope everyone understands this. 
I mean show & hide function also not completed for production (e.g. you should check variable is an object, etc.) - this only for convenience to answer

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible!

add e.g. `onchange="show_div(this.id)"` to each radiobutton you have got.
also write a javascript function like this:

```
function show_div(id)
{
    var exist_div = document.getElementById("exist");
    var new_div   = document.getElementById("new");

    if(id == "exist_radio")
    {
        exist_div.style.display = "block";
        new_div.style.display   = "none";
    }
    else if(id == "new_radio")
    {
        exist_div.style.display = "none";
        new_div.style.display   = "block";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But one problem before clicking the both div are visible. Only one can be visible there..

Comment: then you have to decide which one you want to display first, or if you want to display one element first. just add `style="display:none;"` to the element (div) you do not want to be shown when page loads

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in jQuery quite nicely:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#exist').show();
    $('#new').hide();

    $('#exist_radio').on('click', function() {
           $('#new').hide();
           $('#exist').show();
    });

    $('#new_radio').on('click', function() {
           $('#new').show();
           $('#exist').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: but it doesn't work for me. I don't know why? Is there need any plugin or something

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

events: 
     "click .radio.input" : "showDiv"

```
showDiv:(el)->
    kindOfDiv = el.target.value   
    if kindOfDiv is "existing"
        @$("#exist").show() 
        @$("#new").hide() 

    if kindOfDiv is "new"
        @$("#new").show() 
        @$("#exist").hide()
```